# Disappeared follower glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

OK in Skyrim I had a follower but then they disappeared. I've seen another question a lot like this but the answers to it did not help. I was wondering what quest would teleport me because one of the answers to that other question said that if I got a quest that teleported me automatically  then my Follower would appear next to me.  It was Mjoll the lioness. I went back to where I originally got her (at the Bee and Barb)  and she was there but it says that i already  have a follower but I don't.  I was able to pickpocket my items from her but I still can't have a follower now.  So to summarize what is a quest or quest chain that will teleport me so I can get my follower back?

Answer (score 0):

Try fast traveling to another place. This will allow your follower to be next to you. You can also try waiting for a few hours. You can also go back to where you got your follower. If your follower is a housecarl her or she will be in your house or otherwise in the palace. For example if Lydia is lost, try going back to your Whiterun house to see if she's there. If you don't own a house go to Dragonsreach. If she's not there, it's rumored that Lydia may be in the Hall of the Dead in the catacombs. Same thing with other hold except for some, since you may only find your housecarl in a bought house such as Vindrel Hall and Proudspire Manor. And some cities don't have houses for sale such as Morthal, Dawnstar, Falkreath, and Winterhold in vanilla. Try going to the palace to see if the housecarl is there. If your follower is not a housecarl, like Faendal, you can still find your follower where they live. Faendal lives in Riverwood, so best go there. Your follower was Mjoll yes? Try going back to Riften. She normally hangs out at the stalls.

Comment: Thanks but that isn't helping